How do companies decide the warranty period for a product?
$\text{Question:}$ A firm produces machines with a lifespan, whose distribution has a mean of $\mu$ months and standard deviation of $\sigma$ months. The firm wishes to introduce a warranty scheme in which it would like to replace all the dysfunctional machines with new ones within warranty period. But they do not wish to do so for more than $m\%$ of the machines they produce. If the lifespan of the machine is assumed to follow a normal distribution (or maybe some other distribution), how long a guarantee period should be offered?

I don’t want to do this question just to get the answer. I want to do it to really understand how companies decide on their warranty period, I want to know it deeply. Also, can we somehow minimise this $m\%$ and maximise the warranty period for the benefit of the company?

If you truly want to understand how to find warranty periods, then you need a more realistic question, because in real life nobody truly knows $\mu,$ $\sigma,$ or even the true distribution -- but estimates can be made.  This textbook problem is just an elementary exercise in understanding the definition of a quantile; but the real problem is usually framed as a tolerance limit.

In the real world, the firm would set the price jointly with the warranty length since consumers are willing to pay more for a product with a generous warranty. A solution would have to handle that and make some assumptions about market structure (monopoly, duopoly, monopolistic competition, potential for competitor entry) and whether the warranty might attract high-risk customers or change behavior (a generous warranty might reduce the incentive to maintain the machine). I'm not sure if this is the sort of thing you want to delve into.

@whuber Could you tell me what $P(X \le m)$ or $P(X = m)$ represent here? (where $X$ is a random variable representing lifespan of a machine).

@whuber And I tried to understand Tolerance Intervals but unable to get it. (you can see my response in the comment of answer provided by @jginestet). I will definitely study it after I complete all pre-requisite knowledge.

The answer you are looking for falls under the topic of "Tolerance Intervals" (TI). Tolerance intervals for normal populations are a well covered topic, particularly in industry. You can find good references here (NIST) or here (Air Force) (there are both clearly written and approachable) and a R package here.
Note that you can also compute such TI's for lots of other distributions (binomial, Poisson, etc.); see this R package. And there are also non-parametric methods, but these require larger sample sizes to achieve a reasonable confidence (at least ~100 for a 95% confidence level).
A TI gives you an interval which is likely to contain a certain percentage of the population (coverage), with a certain confidence, e.g. 95% confidence of at least 95% of the population. In your case (survival), one is only interested in a 1-sided interval (lower bound); we want to ensure that at least $p%$ of the product will last a certain time.
The form of a normal TI is $\mu - k_1*\sigma$; k is a so-called k-factor, available from tables, or various software packages. I am using $k_1$ to indicate it is for a one-sided TI. For example, for a sample size of 30, coverage of 95%, and confidence of 95%, $k_1=2.2198$. Note that, even for the normal distribution, there are various methods for computing the "k-factors", some being more or less approximative; so not all sources will give you exactly the same values for k; the differences become very small when N gets large (a few hundreds).
So, with your values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$, it becomes very simple to find the low bound for a commercially acceptable warranty period.
Note that in practice, often a relatively small fraction of the users/owners will actually claim the warranty; in my case, we would expect 30-40% of users to claim a warranty; so we could tolerate a coverage of say, only 90%, knowing that less than half of users would actually make a claim. But this is very product/industry dependent (claims are lower for consumer products, higher for professional products, and are higher for more expensive products).

I tried to understand about Tolerance Intervals but unable to get it. I recently started studying Statistics for my Data Science course. I didn't know finding warranty period requires high level knowledge. I heard from my professor, while studying Statistics, that "How do you think companies decide their warranty, Is it random or do they use some algorithm to find the warranty period?" and became excited after knowing that Statistics is behind all that. But thanks for taking time to answer my question

Tolerance Intervals are a fairly basic concept (undergradf, 1st level stat class). But very much used in industry. Try to read the NIST page; it is short, and clear. You will not understand why the math works, but you should understand the concept.
